# Facebook SDK private posts and private status - Titanium

Tags: facebook, titanium, status

I'm doing both posts and status update using Titanium but it's always private and can't be seen by my friends even if I change its privacy to public. 
I thought it's a privacy problem in the Facebook app I created. But when I changed "Default Activity Privacy" to be "public", friends still can't see my status or my posts.
any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

I could know the problem. It happened because my Facebook app sandbox was on.